# Not able to send value to frontend

Tags: javascript, express

I think I am doing something wrong, I am not able to send value to frontend.
res.json(arr) this line of code give [] blank array.
but console.log(arr); gives all value what I needed(JSON value).

Code

```
    var arr = [];
    var messagesPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        messages.forEach(function (val,index) {
            arr[val.session] = val;
            if (index === messages.length -1) resolve(arr);
        });
    });


    messagesPromise.then((arr) => {
        console.log("######################");
        console.log(arr);  // this line of code gives json value 
        console.log("######################");

        res.json(arr); // this line of code gives [] array
    });
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see the problem ... give an example of `messages` array, I bet the objects have `session` properties that are not numeric

Comment: What you need to do is `var arr = {}` - because you're creating an **object** not an **Array** - note, you can add whatever properties you like to an **Array**, but they will be ignored when converted to JSON

Comment: Please share example of  **messages** array also.

Comment: @SwapnilN - I bet the objects in messages have `session: "not a numeric value"`